# I need a Visual Studio macro to split one CS file with multiple classes into multiple files with single classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macros

I believe that this type of functionality is built into [JetBrains ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which I've actively decided not to use (oh stop with your surprised face and gasping). Nothing against ReSharper, I just like my IDE to be as lightweight as possible.

I've seen a lot of examples going in the opposite direction - taking partial classes and putting them into one file - but nothing to split one multi-class file into multiple single-class files. Obviously, I'd like for said macro to add said files to the project, but I don't mind if that's not possible.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: "Nothing against ReSharper, I just like my IDE to be as lightweight as possible." - umm, notepad then?

Comment: If you refuse to use Resharper, you deserve no help :)

Comment: I'm totally with you brady. I love Resharper, but it slows down the development environment too much. Instead i use CodeMaid, which has many of the features Resharper provides. But the "Split into Files" feature is missing there. :( Did anybody found an alternative solution?